# Using scale_color_manual in ggplot for a custom legend--colors are not matching the code

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, scale-color-manual

I am mapping two independent shapefiles and trying to build a custom legend with the necessary colors.  The colors in the legend are not matching what is in the scale_color_manual command.  Here is the script:

```
plot <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Vista_rebuf, col = "maroon", fill = "purple", show.legend = TRUE) + geom_sf(data = Reno_rebuf, col = "dark green", fill = "green", show.legend =  TRUE)  

plot + ggspatial::annotation_scale( location = "br", bar_cols = c("grey60", "white")) + 
 ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(location = "br", which_north = "true", pad_x = unit(0.1, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.3, "in"), 
       style = ggspatial::north_arrow_nautical(fill = c("grey40", "white"),line_col = "grey20")) + 
 ggtitle("RFC Forecasting Area") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
 scale_color_manual(values = c("Vista" = "purple", "Reno" = "green"), breaks = c("Reno", "Vista")) + 
 theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20), legend.text = element_text(size = 14))
```

This is what it is producing:

[image]

Why isn't the Vista box in the legend purple?

Comment: Are the names "Vista" and "Reno" exactly the same as those used in your data?

Comment: They are--I copied and pasted them to make sure.

Comment: Can you try and put together a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: Actually it's interesting that you get a legend at all as you are not mapping on any aesthetics (but perhaps I missed something), i.e. try with `geom_sf(data = Vista_rebuf, aes(fill = "Vista"), color = "maroon")` and `geom_sf(data = Reno_rebuf, aes(fill = "Reno"), color = "maroon")` and use `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual`

Comment: @Stefan--that did the trick!  The legend now says "fill" at the top.  Do you know how to get that off?  Here is the updated code:

plot <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Vista_rebuf, aes(fill = "Vista"), color = "maroon") + geom_sf(data = Reno_rebuf, aes(fill = "Reno"), color = "dark green") 

plot +  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Vista" = "purple", "Reno" = "green"), breaks = c("Reno", "Vista")) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20), legend.text = element_text(size = 14))

Comment: Add `+ labs(fill = NULL)` to remove the legend title.